# No puedo leer archivo csv dentro de una función

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Hola que tal buenas tardes soy novato en python y estoy aprendiendo por lo cual me eh topado con el siguiente error, tengo un script en python el cual lee archivos csv lo cual eh adaptado el código para leer archivos csv pero al correr todo el fragmento de codigo me genera el error siguiente: ValueError: too many values to unpack   lo cual eh investigado sobre el error pero no encuentro una solución para el presente problema.
Explico dentro de la función Seed, al momento de ejecutar ese fragmento de código funciona bien no me presenta ningún error, ya que me lee la primera fila de ese archivo sin ningún problema, pero al correr todo el script me genera ese error en la linea siguiente: 
day, start, stop, course, room = l.strip().split(',')

```
def import_seed(self):
    schedule=[]
    sessions={}
    f = open(seed_path, 'r')
    f.readline()  # Skipping the header row
    for l in f:
        # Day,Start time,End time,Course ID,Room
        day, start, stop, course, room = l.strip().split(',')
        if course in sessions:
            sessions[course]+=1
        else:
            sessions[course]=0
        schedule.append([weekdays.index(day), textToMin(start), \
                    textToMin(stop)-chunks, room, course, sessions[course]])
    return schedule
```

Uso python 2.7
PD. Espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. Agrega a la pregunta el texto completo del error para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Es posible que el split() este devolviendo mas valores que las variables que tienes para asignar?

Comment: Gracias!!! por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ese problema se da porque el split trae mas campos del que puede asignar. Es decir trae mas de 5 campos. Es probable que el csv exista algun registro con una coma al final del ultimo campo o bien un campo adicional. Lo que se podria hacer en ese caso sin cambiar demasiado el codigo fuente que ya tenes es asignar lo que devuelve el split a una lista para luego recuperar los valores por medio del uso del indice. Quedaria asi

```
 def import_seed():
       schedule=[]
       sessions={}
       f = open(seed_path, 'r')
       f.readline()  # Skipping the header row
       for l in f:

           lista=l.strip().split(',')
           ####Zona del cambio Inicio##############
           day=lista[0]
           start=lista[1]
           stop=lista[2]
           course=lista[3]
           room=lista[4]
           ####Zona del cambio Final########
           if course in sessions:
             sessions[course]+=1
          else:
             sessions[course]=0
```

Espero sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Funciono gracias!!

Comment: @Shadow si funcionó, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Listo! despues de varias seamanas apenas regrese a mi cuenta de stackoverflow